Not closed under ultraproduct, then not closed under "shorter" ultraproduct
The problem
Let $L$ be a first-order logic, $K$ a class of $L$-structures closed under elementary equivalence and $\kappa$ the cardinality of the set containing all formulas of $L$. Prove that if $K$ is not closed under ultraproduct, then there exist ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ and a family of structures $\langle\mathcal{A}_i:i\in\kappa\rangle$ s.t. $$\prod\mathcal{A}_i/\mathcal{F}\notin K$$
My work so far
Proof by contradiction. We know that there exist set $I$, structures $\mathcal{A}_i$ and ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ s.t. $\vert{I}\vert>\kappa$ and $$\mathcal{B}=\prod{\mathcal{A}_i/\mathcal{U}}\notin K$$ Let $\Sigma=Th(\mathcal{B})$. Then for every set $J$ (where $\vert{J}\vert\leq\kappa$) and ultrafilter $\mathcal{V}$ there exists some $\mathcal{A}_h\in K$ s.t. $$\mathcal{A}_h\equiv_e\prod\mathcal{A}_j/\mathcal{V}$$ Is this approach correct? If so, how do I continue from here? I want to use the Compactness Theorem, but don't know how.

$\Sigma$ is of cardinality $\kappa$. So $P_f(\Sigma)$, the collection of all finite subsets of $\Sigma$, has cardinality $\kappa$ as well. For each $T \in P_f(\Sigma)$, by Łoś's theorem, there is an $A_T \in K$ which satisfies $T$. Now follow the proof of compactness theorem and find an ultrafilter $\mathcal{V}$ on $P_f(\Sigma)$ s.t. $\prod_\mathcal{V} A_T$ satisfies $\Sigma = \text{Th}(B)$, so it is elementarily equivalent to $B$. Since $B \notin K$ and $K$ is closed under elementary equivalence, $\prod_\mathcal{V} A_T \notin K$.

So I don't even need my second step?

@DavetheSid I’m honestly not sure what you did in your second step. But regardless, the proof in the answer is basically self-contained.
